# cocos2dx build fail due to undefined symbol

Tags: xcode, compilation, linker, cocos2d-x, game-engine

I am new in Cocos2d and Xcode(as well as game development and mac, I was window and eclipse user). I am working on [programmer guide](https://github.com/chukong/programmers-guide-samples) from coco2dx homepage. I have clone the git and try to run the code, but I am facing compilation error with libcocos2d iOS.a. I have set up library path (to libcocos2d) and header file that caused "cocos2d.h not found" error. But now I have a problem with linker errors. I have googled to figure out build architecture errors but no goods. My current build setting for build architecture is that yes to debug, no to release, architecture is set to standard 64bit x86_64, and valid architectures are -armv7, armv7s, i386, x86_64, and arm64- Can some help me with this?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDevice-ios.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAGLContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDirectorCaller-ios.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCApplication-ios.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDirectorCaller-ios.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDevice-ios.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIColor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDevice-ios.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCApplication-ios.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDevice-ios.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIFont", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDevice-ios.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCImage-ios.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScreen", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDevice-ios.o)
  "_UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification", referenced from:
      -[CCDirectorCaller init] in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDirectorCaller-ios.o)
  "_UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification", referenced from:
      -[CCDirectorCaller init] in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDirectorCaller-ios.o)
  "_UIGraphicsPopContext", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Device::getTextureDataForText(char const*, cocos2d::FontDefinition const&, cocos2d::Device::TextAlign, int&, int&, bool&) in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDevice-ios.o)
  "_UIGraphicsPushContext", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Device::getTextureDataForText(char const*, cocos2d::FontDefinition const&, cocos2d::Device::TextAlign, int&, int&, bool&) in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDevice-ios.o)
  "_UIImageJPEGRepresentation", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::saveToFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCImage-ios.o)
  "_UIImagePNGRepresentation", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::saveToFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCImage-ios.o)
  "AppDelegate::AppDelegate()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "AppDelegate::~AppDelegate()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_glBindVertexArrayOES", referenced from:
      cocos2d::GL::bindVAO(unsigned int) in libcocos2d iOS.a(ccGLStateCache.o)
  "_glDeleteVertexArraysOES", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Renderer::~Renderer() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCRenderer.o)
      cocos2d::MeshCommand::releaseVAO() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCMeshCommand.o)
      cocos2d::TextureAtlas::~TextureAtlas() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCTextureAtlas.o)
      cocos2d::CameraBackgroundSkyBoxBrush::~CameraBackgroundSkyBoxBrush() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCCameraBackgroundBrush.o)
      cocos2d::CameraBackgroundSkyBoxBrush::initBuffer() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCCameraBackgroundBrush.o)
      cocos2d::Physics3DDebugDrawer::~Physics3DDebugDrawer() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCPhysics3DDebugDrawer.o)
      cocos2d::DrawNode::~DrawNode() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDrawNode.o)
  ...
  "_glGenVertexArraysOES", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Renderer::setupVBOAndVAO() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCRenderer.o)
      cocos2d::MeshCommand::buildVAO() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCMeshCommand.o)
      cocos2d::TextureAtlas::setupVBOandVAO() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCTextureAtlas.o)
      cocos2d::CameraBackgroundSkyBoxBrush::initBuffer() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCCameraBackgroundBrush.o)
      cocos2d::Physics3DDebugDrawer::init() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCPhysics3DDebugDrawer.o)
      cocos2d::DrawNode::init() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCDrawNode.o)
      cocos2d::VertexAttribBinding::init(cocos2d::MeshIndexData*, cocos2d::GLProgramState*) in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCVertexAttribBinding.o)
  ...
  "_glMapBufferOES", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Renderer::drawBatchedTriangles() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCRenderer.o)
      cocos2d::TextureAtlas::drawNumberOfQuads(long, long) in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCTextureAtlas.o)
  "_glUnmapBufferOES", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Renderer::drawBatchedTriangles() in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCRenderer.o)
      cocos2d::TextureAtlas::drawNumberOfQuads(long, long) in libcocos2d iOS.a(CCTextureAtlas.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your project settings, go to 'build phases' and in 'Link Binary with Libraries' add 
OpenGLES.framework,UIKit.framework,ImageIO.framework, Foundation.framework and CoreGraphics.framework

clean the project and run again hopefully it start running.